# Cannot re-enable a disabled attribute in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am learning javascript (jquery) and I've programmed a simple quiz. I've come a long way and most if it functions as it should be, however, i find it hard to implement a "ischecked" checker to only allow people to go the next question when they have answered the last question.

The entire quiz is on plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qIqa2mHtIOwZNGS2hSBd

I disable the button in the questionmaker function using this line: `$("<button>Next</button>").addClass("next").prop('disabled', true).insertAfter("form");`

The relevant jquery code:

```
  var blaat = function() {
       var isChecked = $('input[name=group1]:checked').length;
       if (isChecked) {
           $(".form").find(".next").prop('disabled', false);
           var answer = $('input[name=group1]:checked', '#form').next().text();
           checkAnswer(answer);
       }
    };
```

It never fires this line: `$(".form").find(".next").prop('disabled', false);`
Because when i put that line in chromes console it works perfectly. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure your form has a class of 'form'? You referred to it just as 'form' earlier in the code

Comment: You are not handling any event when the user picks an option.

Comment: You need this: `$(".form input").on("change", blaat);` http://jsfiddle.net/hxre3vp5/

Comment: Thanks Melancia, that worked! And I was calling the blaat function of course except not for handling the event on change.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not attaching a handler to the event of changing the `radio` options, so whenever the user picks an answer, nothing is happening.

You just need to add this bit to your code:

`$(".form input").on("change", blaat);`

I also have made some changes, and the final code (suggestion) would look like this:

```
$(function () {
    var allQuestions;

    allQuestions = [{
        question: "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?",
        choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
        correctAnswer: 0
    }, {
        question: "Name the king who failed to keep an eye on things at the battle of Hastings ?",
        choices: ["David Cameron", "Harold", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
        correctAnswer: 1
    }, {
        question: "In which sport would you use a chucker ?",
        choices: ["Ice hockey", "Billiards", "Polo", "Curling"],
        correctAnswer: 2
    }, {
        question: "If a snail climbed up a 12 ft wall at a steady rate of 3 feet a day, but slipped down 2ft every night, how many days would it take him to reach the top ?",
        choices: ["10 days", "9 days", "8 days", "12 days"],
        correctAnswer: 0
    }, {
        question: "Traditionally, what type of wood do Rolls Royce use on the dashboards of their cars?",
        choices: ["Shit", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Walnut"],
        correctAnswer: 3
    }, {
        question: "What is the national emblem of Canada ?",
        choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Maple leaf"],
        correctAnswer: 3
    }, {
        question: "Free Willey was a film about what ?",
        choices: ["David Cameron", "Whale", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
        correctAnswer: 1
    }, {
        question: "What World War II operation was code named `Dynamo` ?",
        choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Evacuation of Dunkirk", "Tony Blair"],
        correctAnswer: 2
    }, {
        question: "How many old pennies were there in a Groat?",
        choices: ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"],
        correctAnswer: 3
    }, {
        question: "In cricket, where would you find the chain ?",
        choices: ["Between the wickets", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
        correctAnswer: 0
    }];

    var correctAnswers = 0;
    var currentQuestion = 0;
    var answer = allQuestions[currentQuestion].choices[allQuestions[currentQuestion].correctAnswer];

    function init() {
        var question = allQuestions[currentQuestion].question;
        var $questions = $(".form input");

        $questions.each(function (index) {
            var choices = allQuestions[currentQuestion].choices[index];
            $(this).next().text(choices);
        });

        $("<h2></h2>").text(question).insertBefore("form");
        $("<button>Next</button>").addClass("next").prop("disabled",true).on('click', addView).insertAfter("form");
    }

    function addView() {
        var $input = $("#form").children(); // $('#form input')

        currentQuestion++;

        $("h2, button").remove();
        $input.prop('checked', false);

        var question = allQuestions[currentQuestion].question;    
        var $questions = $(".form input");

        $questions.each(function (index) {
            var choices = allQuestions[currentQuestion].choices[index];
            $(this).next().text(choices);
        });

        $("<h2></h2>").text(question).insertBefore("form");
        $("<button>Next</button>").addClass("next").prop("disabled", true).on('click', addQuestion).insertAfter("form");
    }

    function addQuestion() {
        if (currentQuestion < 10) {
            addView();
        } 
        else {
            $(".next").on("click", function () { // need to write this function <--
                console.log("it worked!");
            });
        }
    }

    function blaat() {
        var isChecked = $('input[name=group1]:checked').length;

        if (isChecked) {
            $(".form").find(".next").prop("disabled", false);
            var answer = $('input[name=group1]:checked', '#form').next().text();
            checkAnswer(answer);
        }
    }

    function checkAnswer(answer) {    
        var correctAnswer = allQuestions[currentQuestion].correctAnswer;
        var indexAnswer = allQuestions[currentQuestion].choices[correctAnswer];

        if (indexAnswer == answer) {
            correctAnswers++;
            console.log(correctAnswers);
            $(".record").text("You have answered " + correctAnswers + " questions correctly!");
            return answer;
        } 
        else {
            console.log("answer is not correct!");
        }
    }

    $("#start").on("click", function () {
        $(".start").css("display", "none");
        $(".quiz").find(".form").removeClass("hidden");

        init();
    });

    $(".form input").on("change", blaat);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hxre3vp5/)

Comment: Thanks, it fixed that specific problem, but now i new bug has arisen. It now updates the correctanswers value also on every change (so you can have 10 correct answers already on the first question) and not on the click event of the next button. So i have to find a way to check if the same question has been answered already and if so, dont update the value of correctanswers.

Comment: If a different requirement has arisen, you need to open a new question. But I'll look at this in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

I see your code try adding 
 $("input[type='radio']").on("click",blaat); 
in init function